# Convert string to integer in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have written a simple calculate for example but it isnot work

```
a = IO.gets"a = "
a = String.to_integer(a)
b = IO.gets"b = "
b = String.to_integer(b)
v = a + b
IO.puts "Sum: #{v}"
```

How can I correct this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IO.gets` does not trim the trailing newline character which makes `String.to_integer` fail even if you enter only digits. You can remove it using `String.trim_trailing/1`:

```
a = IO.gets("a = ") |> String.trim_trailing
a = String.to_integer(a)
b = IO.gets("b = ") |> String.trim_trailing
b = String.to_integer(b)
v = a + b
IO.puts "Sum: #{v}"
```

```
$ elixir a.exs
a = 123
b = 456
Sum: 579
```

Comment: `a = "a = " |> IO.gets() |> String.trim_trailing() |> String.to_integer()` looks more elixirish :)